# How to display a custom menu in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, navigation, hyperlink

I currently have two different custom menus. I want the first menu "Main" to be displayed at the top of the page as the top navigation. I want the second menu "Slider" under the slider.

I have this at the top:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => '','container' => '',));?>
```

And somehow it's picking up the links in the first menu "Main" and showing it on top. Now I want to display the links from the 2nd menu under the slider

```
<?php register_nav_menu( 'Slider', 'Under Slider Navigation' ); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'Slider','container' => '',));?>
```

And with this, it is showing every single page I Have in the nav bar. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

try the below function

```
  function register_my_menus() {
      register_nav_menus(
        array(
          'Slider' => __( 'Under Slider Navigation' ),

        )
      );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );

    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'Slider' ) ); ?>
```

`register_nav_menus` must be in array

Comment: You must save the needed pages for your 'Slider' menu, Under Appearance - Menus in your wp-admin

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the menu before you register it. Also, ideally this should go into functions.php

```
<?php function my_second_nav(){
    wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'Slider','container' => '',))} 
    register_nav_menu( 'Slider', 'Under Slider Navigation' ); ?>
```

Then position it wherever you want

```
<?php my_second_nav(); ?>
```

Comment: Didn't work :( I put <?php 
function my_second_nav(){
 wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'Slider','container' => '',));            In the functions.php file and  <?php my_second_nav(); ?>  in the header. It still shows links of all the pages I've created